# Mysql Multiple order by

Tags: mysql

I am writing a mysql query , in which i have to order by priority and price. Here is my table structures.

```
TABLE1
------
id | name | priority_order
 1    A        1
 2    B        2
 3    C        0
 4    D        0
 5    E        4
 6    F        0
 7    G        0
 8    H        3
 9    I        5
10    J        0  

TABLE2
------
    id | productid | listname | Color | price 
   100     5012        A        Blue     700
   101     5012        B        Blue     400
   102      "          C        Blue     850
   103      "          A        Red      650
   104      "          H        Red      550
   105      "          B        Red      600  
   106      "          E        Green    780
   107      "          E        Blue     650
   108      "          F        Blue     300           
   109      "          G        Red      355
   110      "          B        Black    550
   111      "          A        Black    480
   112      "          C        Red      800
   113      "          H        Black    785  
   114      "          I        Black    625
   115      "          I        Red      480
```

Now i have to order by low price With Each Priority . i.e i have to show low price in first priority , low price in 2nd priority , low price in 3rd priority ..remaining prices are in their positions.

```
Expected Output :
----------------
       id | productid | listname | Color | price  | priority_order 
       111     5012        A        Black    480        1
       101     5012        B        Blue     400        2  
       104      "          H        Red      550        3
       106      "          E        Blue     650        4
       115      "          I        Red      480        5
=========== The above order is taken low price in each priority ========
=========== Now the remaining should be in any priority order but should be in low price ASC====
       108      "          F        Blue     300        0
       109      "          G        Red      355        0
       110      "          B        Black    550        2
       105      "          B        Red      600        2
       114      "          I        Black    625        5
..................... and so on..
```

The Query i tried is

```
select a.name , a.priority_order , b.color , b.productid , b.price from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.name = b.listname where productid = 5012 order by
case when priority_order = 0 then 2
when priority_order > 0 then 1
b.price ASC
```

Comment: To discover the lowest price for a list of given non-null priorities you'll have to use a subquery with `GROUP BY`. This is a far from trivial problem you're trying to tackle.

Comment: I tried and obtained only the min price of each priority . `select a.name , a.priority_order , b.color , b.productid , min(b.price) as price from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.name = b.listname where productid = 5012
abd priority_order > 0
group by a.name
order by priority_order asc , b.price asc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do the same select twice; once to get the records, once to find the minimum price per priority order. Join these and use the prices to determine the sort order.

```
select b.id , b.productid , b.listname , b.color , b.price , a.priority_order
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.name = b.listname 
inner join
(
  select x.priority_order , min(y.price) as min_price
  from table1 x 
  inner join table2 y on x.name = y.listname 
  --where y.productid = 5012
  group by x.priority_order
) m on m.priority_order = a.priority_order
--where b.productid = 5012
order by
  case when a.priority_order > 0 and b.price = m.min_price then 1 else 2 end,
  a.priority_order,
  b.price;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2af6a/7.

EDIT: Here is an alternative without a derived table, but with an exists clause. This may be considered more readable, but is usually slower when the result set is large, as a lookup select for every single record is needed.

```
select b.id , b.productid , b.listname , b.color , b.price , a.priority_order
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.name = b.listname 
--where b.productid = 5012
order by
  case when a.priority_order = 0 or exists
  (
    select *
    from table1 x 
    inner join table2 y on x.name = y.listname
    where x.priority_order = a.priority_order
    and y.price < b.price 
  ) then 2 else 1 end,
  a.priority_order,
  b.price;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2af6a/5.

Comment: Well, that doesn't tell me anything, as you can imagine. Do you get a syntax error? Too many records? Too few? How are the results different from what you expect?

Comment: No error it return it just return the results in the desc order with non priority values in first.

Comment: Okay, I missed that you want priority order 0 not to be with the first records. I've edited my answer accordinly. I also put columns in desired order and removed `where b.productid = 5012`which is in your query but not in your request. Moreover there were two typos in my first query.

Comment: i need it with `where a.productid = 5012` . Anyway i am trying your query to get desired results for me.

Comment: I've added the `where productid = 5012` conditions again. Uncomment to use them.